# sudo passwd for bash terminal

Tags: bash, sudo, azure, password-recovery, code

I am total newbie so excuse the lack of knowledge, but I recently created an Microsoft Azure account so it comes equipped with a bash terminal. I wanted to make sure it is up-to-date so I tried running "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" command which comes back with
"We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

```
#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

For security reasons, the password you type will not be visible.

[sudo] password for jennifer: "

Can anyone tell me what password I would use there, because I do not remember setting up a sudo account, but I also suffer from short term memory sooooo, it could be me, if so, how do I retrieve said password. Thank you for your guys help in advance:)

Comment: I am the local System Administrator.

Comment: Could this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/troubleshoot/sign-in/forgot-sign-in-password

Answer (score 0):

Normally sudo asks for your own account's password (on the system that you're connected to). That is, you're connected to a Linux system where your account 'jennifer' would have had its password set somehow.

> I recently created an Microsoft Azure account so it comes equipped with a bash terminal.

That sounds like you're accessing "Azure Cloud Shell". That's running on a *temporary* server and deliberately [does not grant you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/limitations#bash-limitations) root access through 'sudo', even if you were able to provide the password. (The account doesn't actually have any password set, if I remember correctly.)

And because it's a temporary server that gets destroyed as soon as you close Cloud Shell (part of why it's free) it doesn't really make practical sense to `apt upgrade` it anyway. Azure's Cloud Shell is practically only meant for brief tasks (mostly managing Azure services through the `az` tool); for anything else, you'll need to create a whole VM on the Azure platform.